# SQL Query Join two Queries with Sum()

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know this is simple for you sql people, but I am trying to combine two simple queries into one. It's probably obvious from the code that job.ActiveJob.ID = job.EstimateTbl.ID_Job.

I'm trying to get:  id, JobName, sum(itemAmount)

Thanks for your help.

```
SELECT a.id, a.JobName
FROM job.ActiveJobsTbl AS a
WHERE a.ID = '100' 

SELECT SUM(itemAmount)
FROM job.EstimateTbl
WHERE ID_Job = '100'
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `JOIN` the tables by the `ON E.ID_Job = A.ID` and get the values in `SELECT` with `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT A.id, A.JobName, SUM(E.itemAmount) AS Amount 
FROM job.ActiveJobsTbl AS A
INNER JOIN job.EstimateTbl E ON E.ID_Job = A.ID 
WHERE A.ID = '100'  
GROUP BY A.id, A.JobName;
```

Comment: Thanks! all the answers worked, but this was closest to what I was imagining. I was very close, but didn't think to put the "E" inside of the SUM().

Answer (score 1):

using `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT a.id, a.JobName,EstimateTbl.itemAmount
FROM job.ActiveJobsTbl AS a
left join
( 
    SELECT SUM(itemAmount) itemAmount,ID_Job
    FROM job.EstimateTbl
    group by ID_Job
) EstimateTbl on  EstimateTbl.ID_Job = a.ID
WHERE a.ID = '100'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `APPLY` :

```
select a.id, a.JobName, t.itemAmount 
from job.ActiveJobsTbl AS a OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT SUM(t.itemAmount) AS itemAmount
      FROM job.EstimateTbl AS t
      WHERE t.ID_Job = a.ID
     ) t
WHERE a.ID = 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.id, A.JobName, SUM(E.itemAmount) AS Amount 
FROM job.ActiveJobsTbl AS A
INNER JOIN job.EstimateTbl E ON E.ID_Job = A.ID 
WHERE A.ID = '100'
GROUP BY A.id, A.JobName;
```